# Taylor series of $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x^4}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

what is the taylor series of $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x^4}$ at $x=0$ I know by the binomial theorem $(1+x^4)^\frac{1}{2}= 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1/2)(1/2-1)(1/2-2)...(1/2-n+1)}{n!}x^{4n}$ but is there any way to simply this?

Comment: Those coefficients are ${1/2}\choose n$

Comment: @Argon Everybody, including Skrrrrrtttt knows that. That is not a simplification.

Comment: @acetone What would be a simplification? Gamma function??

Comment: First you can factor out $-1$: (1/2)(1/2-1)...(1/2-n+1)=(1/2)*(-1)^(n-1)*(1/2)(3/2)(5/2)...((2n-5)/2)((2n-3)/2)$

Comment: and now you can combine the $/2$:$ (1/2)\cdot(-1)^{n-1}\cdot(1/2)(3/2)(5/2)...((2n-5)/2)((2n-3)/2)=(1/2)\cdot(-1/2)^{n-1}\cdot(1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot...\cdot(2n-3))$ unfortunately the product of all the $n-1$ odd numbers is not a nice number and equal to $2^{n-1}\Gamma(n-0.5)/\sqrt \pi$ and you get the not so nice result of $(1/2)\cdot(-1/2)^{n-1}\cdot(1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot...\cdot(2n-3))=(-1)^{n-1}\dfrac{\Gamma(n-0.5)}{2\sqrt\pi}$ where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function

Comment: Well, it called also be written in terms of double factorial ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial ): $$=\frac 12\cdot\left(-\frac12\right)^{n-1}\cdot((2n-3)!!)=\frac 12\cdot\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\cdot\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!}$$

Comment: @Holo so $\sqrt{1+x^4}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac 12\cdot\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\cdot\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!}x^{4n}$?

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt I only did brief review on the question, I think this is true but I might had a mistake in the power somewhere or something similar, I'll rewrite this, this time more organized, to double check and will post it as an answer. But if I didn't done a dumb mistake in the middle, yes, this is the answer(but you need to divide by $n!$ this thing)

Answer (score 0):

Let's ignore the first $1/2$ and the $1/n!$ for now and focus in the interesting part:$$(0.5-1)(0.5-2)\cdots(0.5-(n-1))$$

Notice that every element in this product is negative, so this changes from positive to negative every element, we will now "factor" out $-1$ from every element:$$(0.5-1)(0.5-2)\cdots(0.5-(n-1))=((-1)(1-0.5))((-1)(2-0.5))\cdots((-1)((n-1)-0.5))=(-1)^{n-1}\cdot (1-0.5)(2-0.5)\cdots(n-1.5)=(-1)^{n-1}\cdot 0.5\cdot 1.5\cdots \frac{2n-3}2=(-1)^{n-1}\frac12\cdot\frac32\cdots\frac{2n-3}2$$

In a similar way we did with $-1$ we will multiply all the $1/2$ and move them aside:$$(-1)^{n-1}\frac12\cdot\frac32\cdots\frac{2n-3}2=(-1)^{n-1}0.5^{n-1}\cdot1\cdot3\cdot(2n-3)=(-0.5)^{n-1}\cdot1\cdot3\cdot(2(n-1)-1)$$

Now we have a product of the first $n-1$ odd numbers, this is called [double factorial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) and for odd numbers we have $(2k-1)!!=\frac{(2k)!}{2^k(k!)}$, for us $k$ is $n-1$ so we get:$$(-0.5)^{n-1}\cdot1\cdot3\cdot(2(n-1)-1)=(-0.5)^{n-1}\cdot(2(n-1)-1)!!=(-0.5)^{n-1}\cdot\frac{(2n-2)!}{2^{n-1}\cdot(n-1)!}=(-1)^{n-1}\cdot \left(\frac12\right)^{2n-2}\cdot\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!}$$

Now we will add the previous terms(the one half and and $1/n!$ to get to:$$(-1)^{n-1}\cdot \left(\frac12\right)^{2n-1}\cdot\frac{(2n-2)!}{\underbrace{(n-1)!\cdot n!}_{\text{also equal to: }((n-1)!)^2n}}$$

This is the simplest I could get, so in my comments I had a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{2} - k\right)
&= \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1 - 2k}{2} \\
&= \frac{1 - 2(0)}{2} \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)(2k-1)(2k)}{2(2k)} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^{2(n-1)}} \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(2k-1)(2k)}{k} \\
&= (-1)^{n-1} 2^{1-2n} \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (2k-1)(2k)}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k} \\
&= (-1)^{n-1} 2^{1-2n} \frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!},
\end{align*}$$
consequently $$\frac{1}{n!} \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{2} - k\right) = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{2n-1} n} \binom{2n-2}{n-1}.$$