# What is the Taylor series representation of $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ about $c = 1$ without use of double factorial?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

Hey all I know this question has been asked before, but the other thread has not answered the question I am looking for. I think I found a series representation of $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, but it uses the double factorial $$1 + \frac{1}{2}(x-1)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(2n-3)!!(x-1)^n}{2^nn!}$$

I am fairly sure this representation is correct, but my professor has never introduced us to double factorials so I have a feeling this is not the way he wants us to approach this problem. I have been introduced to binomial series and I feel that might be a better representation, but I am still unsure how to write it as a binomial series, any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: See also: [Taylor series of $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x^4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2709824/272831).

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=1+y$ and consider the expansion of $\sqrt{1+y}$ around $y=0$.

Then using the binomila theorem, you just have
$$\sqrt{1+y}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n} y^n$$ Back to $x$
$$\sqrt{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n} (x-1)^n$$

Comment: This is a similar answer to what I've seen in the other thread, I am not sure this is what I am looking for. Here is what my professor wrote for the question: Compute the Taylor series of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ about $c = 1$. Hint: The first two terms don’t fit the pattern of the remaining terms, so you will need to write those two terms out before writing the rest of the series compactly as an infinite series. This one is a bit
messier than most of the examples we’ve seen up to this point.